# How many generators of the group $U(n)$ are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

Let $U_n$ be $U(\Bbb Z_n)$,  the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$.

Given such group and also we know it is a cyclic group the question is:

> How many generators does it have?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is a oiler group.

Comment: Un = Euler’s group is Un = U(Zn) with mult module n

Comment: Really? Then edit your question and add it to it.

Comment: $\varphi(\varphi (n))$, where $\varphi $ is Euler's totient function.